# multi line die() message

Tags: php, html

Well it's a very simple question but I haven't found the answer. Hopefully it'll not take too much of anyone's time to just show me.

I want to output a multi line `die()` message and I've tried variations of `\r\n` and `PHP_EOL` with quotes  here and not here and things like that: and I can't get it to work.

Here's the basic line I want to edit:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) die("You Will Be Reported For Spam To Your ISP" . mysql_error());
```

I just want to expand that "you will be reported..." into a little para of dire threats..

Comment: what about adding a <br>?

Comment: I've retagged as HTML, assuming that's what you want to generate. Feel free to correct it if I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

That's because whitespace is folded in HTML. If you need to break the line then you will need to do it as HTML does it: with the `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
<?php
    // line breaks will appear if running on command line
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        die("You Will Be Reported\r\nFor Spam To Your ISP" . mysql_error()); 
    }

    // paragraphs will appear on a web page
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        die("<p>You Will Be Reported</p><p>For Spam To Your ISP</p><p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>");
    }

?>
```

Comment: **always** put brackets `{}` around code blocks. oneliner is no exception

Comment: Absolutely. Point taken.

Comment: correct me if Im wrong, but I think that if you don't feed the browser with an appropriate header first, die() will output plain text so your html tags wont work (if using the solution not in html context)

Comment: @Gadoma Let me test that out. Tested `<?php if (1 !== 0) { die ("<p>Testing</p><p>Yah</p>"); } ?>` on a WAMP and LAMP server resulted in HTML output from `die`.

Comment: @zfus thanks for testing, but still it depends on your stack configuration (server and php) - sometimes the default stack config will output text/plain :) So in the discussed case I guess it's safer to put configuration over convention :P Cheers mate,

Comment: @Gadoma yeah, it is indeed safer to put configuration over convention. Thanks for sharing this good point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, if you want to die() preformated text (having \r\n) not in html context just use

```
die("<pre>" . $your_multiline_preformated_text . "</pre>");
```

this should do it. If you want to use HTML tags in your die() output, you need to inform the browser first (so either printout some "< html >< body >" first or feed the browser with a php header 'content-type').